# AngularJS form validation does not work as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

the following code (taken from W3Schools) does not work when I add an additional check for the ng-disabled directive for the submit button. I would like to use "myForm.email.$untouched" as well, so that the submit button is disabled when someone goes on the page right away and the field is empty. But when I add it, I have to click somewhere and only then the button is enabled.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>

    <h2>Validation Example</h2>

    <form ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="validateCtrl" name="myForm" novalidate>

        <p>Email:
            <br>
            <input type="email" name="email" ng-model="email" required>
            <span style="color:red" ng-show="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">
    <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="myForm.email.$error.email">Invalid email address.</span>
            </span>
        </p>

        <p>
            <button ng-disabled="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">Absenden</button>
        </p>

    </form>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('validateCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.user = 'John Doe';
            $scope.email = '';
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Would like to change the code to this but it's not working (have to click somewhere):

```
<p>
<button
ng-disabled="myForm.email.$untouched || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">Absenden</button>
</p>
```

Comment: Make use of $pristine` as instead of `$untouched`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
<p>
<button
ng-disabled="myForm.email.$untouched || myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">Absenden</button>
</p>
```

To

```
<p>
<button
ng-disabled="myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid || myForm.email.$pristine">Absenden</button>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this condition

```
<p>
    <button ng-disabled="myForm.email.$touched && myForm.email.$dirty && myForm.email.$invalid">Absenden</button>
</p>
```